# Query json array column with no name in Oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I am using Oracle19c and I have the following table storing json arrays like below:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_JSON2" 
("JSON_DATA") as
select '["test1"]' from dual union all
select '["test1", "test2"]' from dual union all
select '["test2"]' from dual union all
select '["test3"]' from dual;
```

I want to make a query to retrieve rows that contains both the "test1" and the "test2" elements in the array.

So far I have achieved it with the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST_JSON2
WHERE
JSON_EXISTS(json_data, '$?(@ == "test1")') AND
JSON_EXISTS(json_data, '$?(@ == "test2")');
```

I am wondering if the above can be optimised more - for example I was thinking something like below but it is not pick the row with the array that contains both elements:

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM TEST_JSON2
   WHERE 
   JSON_EXISTS(json_data, '$?(@ == "test1" && @ == "test2")');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `[*]` to explicitly reference the array elements and let `@` reference the containing array:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   TEST_JSON2
WHERE  JSON_EXISTS(json_data, '$?(@[*] == "test1" && @[*] == "test2")')
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | JSON_DATA |
> | --- |
> | ["test1", "test2"] |

*(Note: your final query was implicitly being converted to `JSON_EXISTS(json_data, '$[*]?(@ == "test1" && @ == "test2")')` which will not work as there can never be a single array element that is simultaneously equal to both `"test1"` and `"test2"`.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8a9a2a35f6bfc9371f2b75cdc75915f4)*